# Service Fabric: The EntryPoint Blah.exe is not found

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I did some project renaming and changed the folder structure and now I can't deploy my service fabric app to my local service fabric cluster.

> Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : The EntryPoint IdentityService.exe is not found.

- The app was called `IdentityApp` and is now `TheProject.Identity.App`
- The service was called `IdentityWeb` and is now `TheProject.Identity.Service`

---

**More Log Details**

> Started executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
>
> . 'C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\TheProject\TheProject.IdentityDomain\TheProject.Identity.App\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1' -ApplicationPackagePath 'C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\TheProject\TheProject.IdentityDomain\TheProject.Identity.App\pkg\Debug' -PublishProfileFile 'C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\TheProject\TheProject.IdentityDomain\TheProject.Identity.App\PublishProfiles\Local.5Node.xml' -DeployOnly:$true -ApplicationParameter:@{} -UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade $false -OverrideUpgradeBehavior 'None' -OverwriteBehavior 'Always' -SkipPackageValidation:$true -ErrorAction Stop
>
> Copying application to image store...
>
> Upload to Image Store succeeded
>
> Registering application type...
>
> Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : The EntryPoint IdentityService.exe is not found.
>
> FileName: C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageBuilderProxy\AppType\IdentityAppType\IdentityServicePkg\ServiceManifest.xml
>
> At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service
>
> Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:251 char:9
>
> - Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationPathInImage ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Register-Servic
>
>   eFabricApplicationType], FabricException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : RegisterApplicationTypeErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.RegisterApplicationType
>
> Finished executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
>
> Time elapsed: 00:00:26.1378123
>
> The PowerShell script failed to execute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `TheProject.Identity.Service\PackageRoot\ServiceManifest.xml` I had to change the `<Program>` to match the new exe name

```xml
<!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>TheProject.Identity.Service.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
</CodePackage>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also encounter this issue, i got the below two parameters was different in *.csproj file.

```
<AssemblyName>servicename</AssemblyName>
<RootNamespace>servicename</RootNamespace>
```

Maybe it might be helpful for somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't rename services in my project, but I faced the same error couple of days ago. After a lot of time of deep into the issue, I got its reason finally.

I had this line in service's *.csproj file:

```
<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
```

And after removing this string everything started working. I'm not sure why Azure's team didn't provide the much more obvious error in this case.

Maybe it might be helpful for somebody else.

Comment: FYI, they are pretty good about responding to improvement ideas via [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Build configuration was wrong in my case, it was set to release for Debug.

Right click on the solution -> Configuration Manager, change to debug for your project

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem . I updated the serviceManifest.xml as below and got the issue resolved

```
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
  <SetupEntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>SetupEntryPointTasks.exe</Program>
        <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="20480"/>
      </ExeHost>
    </SetupEntryPoint>
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>aaa.exe</Program>
        <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="20480" />
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
```